# Swift scroll view not scrolling (all constraints based)?

Tags: swift, scrollview

I have a scroll view, but it's not scrolling. And I am setting everything based on constraints.

This is how I am adding everything:

```
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


    self.scrollView.addSubview(self.collectionView)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(segmentedControl)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(selectThemLabel)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(customButtonLabel)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(numOfButtonsLabel)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(enableMoreButtonLabel)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(BarLabel)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(changeButtonLabelView)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(enableButtonControl)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(dropDownButton)
```

So the constraints of the scrollview is set based on constraints, and every single subview I have above is also being set use constraints:

```
{
    super.setConstraints()

    BarLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    BarLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    BarLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: labelHeight).isActive = true
    BarLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: labelWidth).isActive = true

    //collectionView
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: BarLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    selectThemLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
    selectThemLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    selectThemLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: labelHeight).isActive = true
    selectThemLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: labelWidth).isActive = true

    segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: selectThemLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    segmentedControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    segmentedControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    segmentedControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    customButtonLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.bottomAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
    customButtonLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    customButtonLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: labelHeight).isActive = true
    customButtonLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: labelWidth).isActive = true

    numOfButtonsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customButtonLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    numOfButtonsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    numOfButtonsLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    numOfButtonsLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    dropDownButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numOfButtonsLabel.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    dropDownButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    dropDownButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numOfButtonsLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    dropDownButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numOfButtonsLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true

    enableButtonLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numOfButtonsLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    enableButtonLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    enableButtonLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    enableButtonLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    enableButtonControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: enableButtonLabel.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    enableButtonControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    enableButtonControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: enableButtonLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

enableButtonControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: enableButtonLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true

    changeButtonLabelView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: enableButtonLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    changeButtonLabelView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    changeButtonLabelView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    changeButtonLabelView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    labelTableHeight = changeButtonLabelView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(dataSource.count) * inputTableCellHeight)
    labelTableHeight.isActive = true
}
```

It is still not scrolling?? Why??

**Update:**

So it is scrolling (sort of), the problem is the last table view is being cut off from my screen, and when I scroll, the indicator is showing that I am scrolling down, but the bottom table view is still being cut off... I don't know why

Comment: the constraints seems fine. It'll be helpful if you can upload an image (or images) of what you are getting, and how you wish to get.

Comment: @RevanthKausikan can't upload image. But it is what I described, so at the bottom of the screen is a table view, and it's being cut off, and scroll view is not scrolling to reveal the rest of the table view.

Comment: Okay. Are the contents of the table view filled dymanically? or are they static?

Comment: @RevanthKausikan So the content is static, at least when it's getting initialized first,  var changeLabelDataSource: [String] = buttonLabelArray, this is the array I am using for filling the table, the buttonLabelArray is a constant

Comment: Okay... Can you let me know if this link helps? Especially above the heading "To preview your interface": https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html